# camera1394: No cameras found

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have camera connected through firewire:

```
$ lsfirewire
fw0: Linux Firewire Juju
fw1: Point Grey Research Flea2 FL2G-50S5C
```

However, when I try to run `camera1394_node` I get:

```
$ rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node 
[ERROR] [1351859527.447323402]: [camera] device open failed: [Camera1394::open]: No cameras found
```

I have tested the camera on another machine and it worked without problems. This machine does not have graphical interface so coriander is not an option here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47330/camera1394:-no-cameras-found/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-02**:
Did camera1394_node work on the other machine?

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-11-04**:
Yes, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far, there is no evidence of a ROS driver problem. The Flea 2 is known to work with `camera1394`, and your camera works with it on another system.

You may be able to run `coriander` (slowly) on a system with a display by using a remote X connection.

If that does not work and presuming the driver and the camera do work, the next step is to check the stuff in the middle.

- Is the 1394 cable working? Maybe try a different one.
- Is the 1394 host adapter on your headless system good? Apparently it found the device, but there could still be troubles actually talking to it.
- Is this kernel firewire driver identical to the one on the system that worked? (Probably OK, Juju is the latest firewire driver for Linux.)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0